# Probability Optimization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, probability

I want to use matlab to solve a straightforward optimization problem, but I'm confused as to what the best tool to use would be. The problem is as follows.

I am running a simple test experiment, in which I have a country that has assets and debts.

I know that its debts will grow at 6% every year no matter what. I also know that its assets will grow at an average of 7%, but with an unknown standard deviation of growth from year to year. As such, there is a probability that assets will be less than debts in a given year.

Given these growth rates, I want to find the lowest volatility of assets such that the probability of assets being less than debts is greater than 90% for 25 years.

How would I solve this constrained optimization problem in Matlab? I have been trying to use fmincon, but I am having difficulty setting up the problem as I've described it here, and for solving specifically for a probability as a constraint.

**EDIT**

Question and simulation approach continued here:
[Finding the Optimum Input for a Simulation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762956/finding-the-optimum-input-for-a-simulation-in-matlab)

Comment: I think I would start very simple with a simulation model and then bisection on the standard deviation.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I've tried your approach by setting up a simulation model, but could you clarify implementing bisection method here? I posted my question separately here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762956/finding-the-optimum-input-for-a-simulation-in-matlab

Comment: See [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).

Comment: I don't quite understand this probability being greater... Are you looking for std of assets where: "90% chance that at least once in 25 years, assets will grow less than 6% = once assets will grow relatively less than debt"? Just calculate this directly. Or do you want "90% chance that at least once in 25 years, `prod(assets) < 1.06^n` = if debts and assets started at the same value, once assets will grow absolutely less than debts". Or something else (say ending with higher relative growth of debt than assets after 25 years)? These are more difficult.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Let `x` be the stdev (decision variable). Let `P(x)` be your probability (result of simulation). We are looking for `x` such that `P(x)=0.9`. This is finding a root of `F(x)=P(x)-0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization problem can be very complex also like it could be multi-time-variate, non-linear, with complex conjugates [*in easy words may be composed of time-varying equations of multiple-variables with non-linear in nature (having gaps or discontinuities) and variables depends on complex functions like sin(exp(X^0.6/7))*].

In such cases most of optimization techniques will fail. You should try to develop model on **Particle Swarn Optimization** which is fairly simple, fast and generic. Idea here is lets say you want to find function f on `z = f(x,y)` divide (x,y) plane in equal squares (*some may have infinite values or discontinuities*). On each square place a bird or point (Xn, Yn) and find function value. Out of all birds one will have lowest value whose coordinate could be your `optimized results` in first run. Now move birds randomly inside the room by small amount (dX, dY) and find new minimum out of `current birds and previous minimum`. Keep on doing till area is sufficiently covered and you'll get fairly optimized result.

Comment: Constraints will act as boundaries for moving birds, that is changing values of (Xn, Yn)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this could work. But is this problem not solveable using normal nonlinear optimization? If I simplify by assuming that the distribution of assets is normally distributed, does that simplify computing the probability? I have a well-defined distribution and mean, and my constraint is that (assets/liabilities >= 90%), and I want to solve for the lowest standard deviation that will produce this amount. If that can't be set up easily in Matlab, which part should I modify?

Comment: Suggested solution is generic and well tested :). Plus regarding `non-linear constrained optimization`, MATLAB is one of the best. See [this article](https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) explaining optimization functions related.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [*WinBugs*](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-winbugs/)?

When you have unknown variance of a distribution, that's crying out for hyper-parameters, and that's what WinBugs is really good at.

Comment: thank you - I am confused I think. if I know that the assets will follow a normal distribution, would that simplify the optimization? in this case I'd have a well defined mean, probability distribution and a constraint that "assets/liabilities >= 90% in years 1-25". If I wanted to find the lowest standard deviation of returns that would guarantee that constraint is met, could that not be solved iteratively given the information above? which part of the problem would make techniques such as fmincon impossible?

Comment: @beeba: Your problem is a little hard for me to visualize, because I'm more accustomed to pharmacometric problems, where there are observations. But WinBugs is Bayesian, which means every parameter has a prior distribution. They simplify Gaussian distributions by parameterizing by precision, not variance or standard deviation. The reason for doing that is the precision has a nice chi-square prior distribution. So if you make that suitably wide so it is "uninformative", it will do a nice job of estimating the precision for you.