# Finding the Optimum Input for a Simulation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulation

I have the following simulation running in Matlab. For a period of 25 years, it simulates "Assets", which grow according to geometric brownian motion, and "Liabilities", which grow at a fixed rate of 7% each year. At the end of the simulation, I take the ratio of Assets to Liabilities, and the trial is successful if this is greater than 90%.

All inputs are fixed except for Sigma (the standard deviation). My goal is to find the lowest possible value of sigma that will result in a ratio of assets to liabilities > 0.9 for every year.

Is there anything in Matlab designed to solve this kind of optimization problem?

The code below sets up the simulation for a fixed value of sigma.

```
%set up inputs

    nPeriods = 25;
    years = 2016:(2016+nPeriods);
    rate = Assumptions.Returns;

    sigma    = 0.15; %This is the input that I want to optimize

    dt       = 1;
    T        = nPeriods*dt;
    nTrials = 500;
    StartAsset = 81.2419;



%calculate fixed liabilities

    StartLiab = 86.9590;
    Liabilities = zeros(size(years))'
    Liabilities(1) = StartLiab
    for idx = 2:length(years)
        Liabilities(idx) = Liabilities(idx-1)*(1 + Assumptions.Discount)
    end




 %run simulation
    obj = gbm(rate,sigma,'StartState',StartAsset);
    %rng(1,'twister');
    [X1,T] = simulate(obj,nPeriods,'DeltaTime',dt, 'nTrials', nTrials);

 Ratio = zeros(size(X1))

for i = 1:nTrials

 Ratio(:,:,i)= X1(:,:,i)./Liabilities;

end

 Unsuccessful = Ratio < 0.9
 UnsuccessfulCount = sum(sum(Unsuccessful))
```

Comment: I doubt that there would be something specific in matlab for this purpose but numerical methods can solve this quite easily.

Comment: Yes you're correct, in fact Excel Solver can find a solution for a similar problem with a single trial quite easily. My issue is more in terms of implementing that kind of optimization with the simulation framework I've set up here. I basically am trying to say "minimize Sigma such that sum(Unsuccessful) = 0", but I'm unsure of how to implement that in Matlab specifically

Comment: When you say lowest you mean it does behave linearly?

Comment: Let me rephrase, I am saying "lowest" as in: there's potentially many different values of sigma that will result in a simulation where the ratio is greater than 0.9 for each year for all (or >95%) trials. Of the set of sigma values that meet this criteria, I want to pick out the lowest in terms of magnitude.

Comment: OK. I have an idea. `fminbnd` would do I guess. I give it a try.

Comment: This worked brilliantly. I converted my code to a function instead of a subroutine, then passed that function to fminbnd, and that found an optimal solution. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your simulation a function that takes `sigma` as the input:

```
function f = asset(sigma)
%set up inputs

nPeriods = 25;
years = 2016:(2016+nPeriods);
rate = Assumptions.Returns;

%sigma    = %##.##; %This is the input of the function that I want to optimize

dt       = 1;
T        = nPeriods*dt;
nTrials = 500;
StartAsset = 81.2419;



%calculate fixed liabilities

StartLiab = 86.9590;
Liabilities = zeros(size(years))'
Liabilities(1) = StartLiab
for idx = 2:length(years)
    Liabilities(idx) = Liabilities(idx-1)*(1 + Assumptions.Discount)
end




%run simulation
obj = gbm(rate,sigma,'StartState',StartAsset);
%rng(1,'twister');
[X1,T] = simulate(obj,nPeriods,'DeltaTime',dt, 'nTrials', nTrials);

Ratio = zeros(size(X1))

for i = 1:nTrials

Ratio(:,:,i)= X1(:,:,i)./Liabilities;

end

Unsuccessful = Ratio < 0.9
UnsuccessfulCount = sum(sum(Unsuccessful))
f = sigma + UnsuccessfulCount
end
```

Then you can use `fminbnd` (or `fminsearch` for multiple inputs) to find the minimized value of sigma.

```
Sigma1 = 0.001;
Sigma2 = 0.999;
optSigma = fminbnd(asset,Sigma1,Sigma2)
```

Comment: one other question - why do you need to do f = sigma + UnsuccessfulCount? instead of just f = UnsuccessfulCount

Comment: @beeba Because you want the Count to be zero (or minimized) for the minimum sigma.